Azure get EID List with API
I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve a list of EID users from our tenant using the Azure API. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this?
Specifically, I'm looking for detailed steps or a sample code (preferably in Python) that can help me authenticate and query the necessary endpoints to get the EID user list. Any pointers on the required permissions and configurations would also be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

App registrations
Create Client secrets
Create Lambda Function

import os
import json
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    tenant_id = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
    client_id = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID']
    client_secret = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET']

    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    token = credential.get_token("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").token
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        users = response.json()
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(users)
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': response.status_code,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Failed to fetch users'})
        }


I can get
{
  "statusCode": 403,
  "body": "{\"error\": \"Failed to fetch users\"}"
}


[ask] and [mre]

Can you include more information on what did you try?

@Rukmini Sure! I added my trial in the question!

Check my answer below you need to grant User.Read.All application API permission  and modify the code to print the json

To list Microsoft Entra ID users, you need to grant User.Read.All application API permission:

And make use of below Python code:
import os
import json
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    tenant_id = 'TenantID'
    client_id = 'ClientID'
    client_secret = 'ClientSecret'

    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    token = credential.get_token("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").token
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        users = response.json()
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(users)
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': response.status_code,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Failed to fetch users'})
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    result = lambda_handler(None, None)  
    if result['statusCode'] == 200:
        users_data = json.loads(result['body'])
        print(json.dumps(users_data, indent=2))  
        print("Press any key to continue . . .") 
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch users:", result['body'])  




Glad that I could help
